# Redirecting to old domain, tried everything, nothing works

Tags: redirect, domain, options

I've moved a Wordpress site from one domain to another. I have changed the `siteurl` and `home` options in the `wp-options` table, added this tags into `wp-login.php` file:

`update_option('siteurl', 'http://my.new.domain' );
update_option('home', 'http://my.new.domain' );`

and I've tried to rewrite the URL using these tags in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://my.new.domain');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://my.new.domain');
```

When I enter `http://my.new.domain` to the address bar, I'm redirected to my old domain. But `http://my.new.domain/wp-admin` is normally accessible. In the settings I can even see the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` with the correct values.

Is there any way to fix this? I have tried (as described above) everything I have found on the web and I am beginning to feel very hopeless.

(Sorry for my English mistakes.)

Comment: It may be the old browser cache! Try with private browsing or by adding query string `http://my.new.domain/?random_string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Sumit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221905/redirecting-to-old-domain-tried-everything-nothing-works#comment325756_221905) pointed out, the problem was in the old browser cache. The solution was to clear browser cache (or just add a query string after the address: `http://my.new.domain/?random_string`).

Thank you.

Comment: Or use incognito mode